Why am I getting "not a valid identifier" when trying to read a tmp file in a bash script?
I am using a bash script with some inline python to read a JSON API. I take a small part of the output and dump it into a temporary file. I know that the temporary file exists, because I am able to run a head operation on it. However, when it comes time to actually iterate over the lines in the file, I get an error like read: /tmp/temporary_tag_storage.H9hEH6': not a valid identifier
Here is the full relevant part of my script:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

getTagByNumber () {
    SOMETHING=$(curl -s 'https://localhost:8000/api/tagstubs' | \
        python3 -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)[$1]['tag'])")
    echo "$SOMETHING" >&3
}

TAGNUMBER=0;
tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/temporary_tag_storage.XXXXXX)
# create file descriptor 3 for writing to a temporary file so that
# echo ... >&3 writes to that file
exec 3>"$tmpfile"
# create file descriptor 4 for reading from the same file so that
# the file seek positions for reading and writing can be different
exec 4<"$tmpfile"
while [ $TAGNUMBER -lt 5 ]
do
    getTagByNumber $TAGNUMBER $TAGS
    TAGNUMBER=$(( $TAGNUMBER + 1 ))
done

#This works, dutifully spitting out five lines of text.
head -n $TAGNUMBER <&4

#So why does this give me "not a valid identifier"?
while read $tmpfile; do
  echo "$p"
done
#rm "$tmpfile"

... and here is the output:
politics
sports
religion
film
television
./createtags.sh: line 83: read: `/tmp/temporary_tag_storage.H9hEH6': not a valid identifier

As you can see, the first attempt to read the tags is successful, spitting out a bunch of topic names. That's why I'm so confused about the second while loop failing.
I've tried putting double quotes around $tmpfile variable name in the definition of the second while loop, and that doesn't seem to help.
Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

What does read do with its arguments?

(to ask the question from a different perspective, why do you think read $tmpfile is going to put anything into $p?)

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag. Also, follow the advice at correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization.

Typical use is:
while read variable_name
do
    ... some action ...
done < input_source

In your case variable_name == /tmp/temporary_tag_storage.H9hEH6 which is a nonsensical variable name hence the error message
Inside your while loop you reference variable $p but never set it.  I'm guessing what you really want is something like:
while read -r p
do
    echo "$p"
done < "$tmpfile"

On each pass through the loop variable p contains the contents of a single line from $tmpfile
